# SP 2013 - Quick edit with Managed Meta Data columns, copy and paste from excel

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to migrate a meta data from an excel spreadsheet to a SP 2013 document library. The columns are managed meta data columns with pre defined terms matching the data in the excel spreadsheet.

However I cannot copy and paste data from excel via Quick Edit in the doucment library without getting the following error "The data returned from the tagging UI was not formatted correctly"

This happens even when I remove all formatting or paste to notepad first.

Are there any simple solutions to this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii7fL.jpg

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Any metadata fields are in fact foreign keys, as it were, to a dynamic, hidden table (or 'list', whatever you want to call it) within SharePoint. To paste a value into a metadata column, you need to know your element's guid (as in, within the term set) and then append that to each metadata element you're pasting in as a <name>|<guid> pair.

**Getting the GUID for an element within your term set**

Browse to [site-root]/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx and create a new view (or edit the default one) to display the field 'IdForTerm'.

Where you have a term 'apple', your IdForTerm may look like '1288beaf-82e0-4d81-b9de-ad5ad8382938'. Take a note of the guid for each term which appears within your input data.

**Edit your input to correctly reference each term**

Let's say you're importing your data from an Excel spreadsheet. Or from a CSV. It doesn't really matter. What you need to do is, basically, a find and replace down each managed metadata column, replacing 'term' with 'term|guid'. So our example from earlier, with the apple, would become 'apple|1288beaf-82e0-4d81-b9de-ad5ad8382938'.

Finally, assuming your view is set up in exactly the same order as your input data, you should be able to 'edit list' from within the browser, hit the leftmost side of your first input row (to select the entire row) and CTRL+V all of your data at the same time.

Note there appears to be a limit to the number of entries you can make at the same time. It appears to sit at around 5,000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @rmacd's answer, you can also get the GUID for a given MMS term by first manually entering the value(s) you need in a Quick Edit cell, then copy and paste the same value(s) from SharePoint to Excel.  The pasted value will appear with the full term|guid that you need to complete the bulk copy/paste.